# Is there an Old Chinese dictionary which shows clearly the usage of a word?

Tags: dictionary, old-chinese

类似于OALD等英语学习者词典，我希望这本词典能在含义之外详细说明词的用法，以使得读者看完后能够用所查的词写出正确的古汉语句子。

以“语”字为例，我希望这本词典至少能够说明这个字（作“告诉”讲时）如何接续表示“告诉”的对象，如何接续表示“告诉”的内容，并给出相应例句。

词典本身是用任何语言编纂的都可以。

Comment: 说清楚你的“古汉语”的范围 。 
朝代更换会改变用词，不是特定朝代的研究学者，都未必搞得清楚那个时代词语的用处。

Comment: There's both [Kangxi](http://www.zdic.net/z/25/kx/9053.htm) and [Shuowen](http://www.zdic.net/z/25/sw/9053.htm) in zdic.net.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

古漢語既常以單字爲詞，容個人推薦 **《王力古漢語字典》**。

我也很贊成@水巷孑蠻的建議，應該用繁體讀古文。不但有簡繁轉換一對多的一個問題，古文裏假借與通假字甚多，分析古文的時侯字與詞的聲、調、韻等十分重要。簡體新造字用的聲部多數都不符合古漢語的聲韻。

例：《王力古漢語字典》「語」字詞條：

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Classical / literary chinese is a fuzzy language, and there are subtle differences amongst dynasties, authors. Using dictionaries to learn how to write, is, well, side way (歧路).

Understanding particles (虛字) and "pausing at the end of a phrase or sentence" (句讀) are crucial. After managing these two skills, one could write naturally.

For particles (虛字), the internet archive has these free materials:

[言文一貫虛字使用法](https://archive.org/details/yanwenyiguanxuzi008800)

[虛字說](https://archive.org/details/02076148.cn)

[經傳釋詞](https://archive.org/search.php?query=%E7%B6%93%E5%82%B3%E9%87%8B%E8%A9%9E&and[]=creator%3A%22%28%E6%B8%85%29%E7%8E%8B%E5%BC%95%E4%B9%8B%E6%92%B0%22)

[chinesische grammatik](https://archive.org/details/chinesischegram00gabegoog), this one is in german, correlated with 經傳釋詞.

[a guide to wenli styles and chinese ideals](https://archive.org/details/guidetowenlistyl00morg)

Then, the internet archive also has the imperial collection of four (四庫全書), in which all text are not punctuated, good for 句讀.
[四庫全書](https://archive.org/search.php?query=%E5%9B%9B%E5%BA%AB%E5%85%A8%E6%9B%B8)

Lastly, learn to read and write classical / literary Chinese in the traditional script.